# Баг или нет? Input с маленьким font-size

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Столкнулся с неожиданностью в Chrome. Если создать `<input>` с `font-size` от 0 до 0.01cm, то при попытке получить содержимое `<input>` JavaScript передаётся пустая строка. Также, если попробовать отправить форму (просто форму, без JS), содержимое тоже не передастся. Это ошибка или нет?

В Firefox работает корректно.

Пример:

```js
function check() {
  alert(document.form.text.value);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="return check();">
  <input type="text" name="text" style="width: 5cm; height: 1cm; font-size: 0.01cm">
</form>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76352/discussion-on-question-by-----input---font-size).

Comment: Зачем извращаться и делать такую ерунду? Вы читали спецификацию `font-size`, видимо нет, так прочитайте и впредь, не делайте таких глупостей, если вы хотите убрать текст с глаз, но. чтобы он был, используйте лучше для таких целей `text-indent`. А убирать с поля видимость коретки - глупо, вы даже и вставить текст не сможете, не говоря о напечатать, хотя с автокомплита будет работать - но это немного другое.

Comment: @And, верстал эту страницу для себя.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function check() {
  console.log(form.text.value);
  return false;
}
check()
```

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="return check();">
  <input type="text" name="text" style="width: 5cm; height: 1cm; font-size: 0.01cm" value="val">
</form>
```

Comment: и в чем суть ответа?

Comment: @Air, у меня всё работает. а у вас?

Comment: И так понятно, что работает... В чем суть ответа?

Comment: Если бы проходило с `value=""`, то ещё ладно. Но если значение атрибута не будет пустым, оно будет автоматически дописываться в начало, если его не стереть, и без JS отправляемые данные (в случае submit) не исправить.

Comment: @Air, вот вам понятно, интересно, откуда ,если автор говорит, что не работает

Comment: @qwabra автор говорит, что отправлять с "довеском" `val` не есть хорошо, а если его стереть из поля, то ничего не отправится. И ладно бы `val` нельзя было стереть - можно бы было силами кода обрезать значение. А вот если пользователь сам сотрёт, то всё - приехали. Хотя тот факт, что при наличии предустановленного значения вообще работает, - тоже весьма занятен.

Comment: угу. бага. (что-то я очень сомневаюсь в том, что они с этим согласятся) css который ломает js - бага же